# Blank homepage SAS Visual Analytics 7.5

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

quick question. How comes my client receives an empty homepage after he logs in on SAS Visual Analytics 7.5? Where is the Welcome field, where is the favorite field? Where are the recent opened files? These are only available when I log in with my own account.

He only sees the reports after he clicks on the report viewer. Someone experience with this? Thank you.

Comment: Are they at www.myhost.com/SASVisualAnalyticsHub?

Comment: @StuSztukowski Yes thats exactly the link they are using yes.

Comment: Gotcha. It sounds like it could be either permission related or config related. If you log in as an admin, does the page work? If so, create a test account with the same metadata permissions as your client and see if the issue is replicable. That will help narrow down where the issue lies. Also, are they using the same browser as you (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, or Opera)?

Comment: Yes. If we log in as an admin we enter SAS VA through the Home Page. We then see the full page with with the recent opened dasboards, with the welcome field, the favorite field etc. The client received a complete empty home page field, only after moving to the Report Viewer he sees the recent opened dasboards.

Comment: The next step would be to verify their permissions using a test account that has their exact permissions. If the behavior occurs there, then you'll know that you need to enable or change some settings. If it doesn't, then it's something specific on their end such as browser incompatibility or some specific security setting at their organization that's interfering with the Hub.